If x is float numbers representable values (eg:0.5) and x+x has no overflow or underflow, and x is not NaN, is x+x-x always equals to x?
Note: I'm not asking about Is floating-point math broken? because those question is about the value difference between decimal value and float number values, but in my case, no decimal values are involved and x is already rounded to the exact value of a float number (eg:x=0.5, or something like var x=0.1), also I'm asking about x+x-x (eg:0.5+0.5-0.5), not the case that x+y-y (eg:0.5+0.1-0.1);
For example, when writing some formula, if I see something like:
x+x-x+...

(x+x-x is at the start) which if x+x has no overflow or underflow, is the result remains the same after simplifying to:
x+...

? Because I think x+x is just the exponent of the float number*2, but matissa remains unchanged, and x+x-x is just the exponent *2 and then /2, so I think it should be the same as x, but I'm not sure if it is correct.
Also I test some random numbers, which seems hold after running the following several times:


for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
  var r=Math.random();
  if(r+r-r!=r){
    alert(r);
    break;
  }
}



I ask it because I don't know if subtraction of float number has some unexpected natures that 2 * x - x would round to another values other than x, also I don't know if x+x is exactly equal to 2 * x.

Does NaN count? If yes, then no.

The obvious answer is “yes, x - x + x === x”.  Regardless of whether this calculation is done by doubling the exponent or by more standard subtraction and addition - Do you have a reason to suspect this is not true?

If the floating-point format uses base two, which JavaScript uses, then yes. Otherwise, possibly not.
If the floating-point format uses base two, then x is represented in the
form ±F•2e, for some significand F and integer exponent e. Then the real-number arithmetic result of x+x is ±F•2e+1, and this is representable in the floating-point format as long as e+1 does not exceed the exponent range. Since we are told there is no overflow, e+1 does not exceed the exponent range, and therefore the computed result of x+x is ±F•2e+1. Then subtracting x from this produces x.
With other bases, this is not necessarily true. Consider x = 777 in a three-digit decimal format. Then 777+777 = 1554 in real-number arithmetic, but 777 + 777 produces 155•101 in the floating-point format, due to rounding to three significant digits. Then 155•101 − 777 produces 773.
